# Add new node ended with 'apt-get install' failed

Tags: cassandra, ubuntu-14.04, datastax, opscenter

**disclaimer: I am a total noobie with both Cassandra and Linux.**

Hello,
I have installed Cassandra Datastax Enterprise  on a VM (created with HyperV on Windows 10) with Ubuntu 14.04. 
On the same VM I've also installed OpsCenter. Let's call this **VM1**.

In another Ubuntu virtual machine, this time created with Parallels on a Mac, I have installed antoher instance of Cassandra Datastax Enterprise. Let's call it **VM2**.

During the installation of Datastax on VM2, I set the seed IP option with the ip address of VM1.The same value has been set for the OpsCenter IP.
I have also set the same cluster name of VM1 on VM2.

I am able to connect to both nodes using DevCenter, but when I try to add the node to the OpsCenter, the operation always fails.
Usually I pass with success these steps:

- Transferring agent files to the destination node
- Running agent installation script
- Waiting for agent to start
- Updating list of available packages

but it always fail when it comes to the 'Installing packages' step, specifically on the **dse-libhadoop_4.8.1-1_all.deb** package.

[image]

Here the error details

```
Install Errored: 'apt-get install' failed
exit status: 100

stdout:
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dse dse-demos dse-full dse-hive dse-libcassandra dse-libhadoop
  dse-libhadoop-native dse-libhive dse-liblog4j dse-libmahout dse-libpig
  dse-libsolr dse-libspark dse-libsqoop dse-libtomcat dse-pig
0 upgraded, 16 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/528 MB of archives.
After this operation, 612 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package dse-libhadoop.
(Reading database ... 227579 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../dse-libhadoop_4.8.1-1_all.deb ...
/usr/share/dse/backups exists, indicating a prior standalone installation. Please remove that first
Selecting previously unselected package dse-libhadoop-native.
Preparing to unpack .../dse-libhadoop-native_4.8.1-1_amd64.deb ...
/usr/share/dse/backups exists, indicating a prior standalone installation. Please remove that first
Selecting previously unselected package dse-libcassandra.
Preparing to unpack .../dse-libcassandra_4.8.1-1_all.deb ...
/usr/share/dse/backups exists, indicating a prior standalone installation. Please remove that first
Selecting previously unselected package dse.
Preparing to unpack .../archives/dse_4.8.1-1_all.deb ...
/usr/share/dse/backups exists, indicating a prior standalone installation. Please remove that first
Selecting previously unselected package dse-libhive.
Preparing to unpack .../dse-libhive_4.8.1-1_all.deb ...
/usr/share/dse/backups exists, indicating a prior standalone installation. Please remove that first
Selecting previously unselected package dse-hive.
Preparing to unpack .../dse-hive_4.8.1-1_all.deb ...
/usr/share/dse/backups exists, indicating a prior standalone installation. Please remove that first
Selecting previously unselected package dse-demos.
Preparing to unpack .../dse-demos_4.8.1-1_all.deb ...
/usr/share/dse/backups exists, indicating a prior standalone installation. Please remove that first
Selecting previously unselected package dse-libpig.
Preparing to unpack .../dse-libpig_4.8.1-1_all.deb ...
/usr/share/dse/backups exists, indicating a prior standalone installation. Please remove that first
Selecting previously unselected package dse-pig.
Preparing to unpack .../dse-pig_4.8.1-1_all.deb ...
/usr/share/dse/backups exists, indicating a prior standalone installation. Please remove that first
Selecting previously unselected package dse-libtomcat.
Preparing to unpack .../dse-libtomcat_4.8.1-1_all.deb ...
/usr/share/dse/backups exists, indicating a prior standalone installation. Please remove that first
Selecting previously unselected package dse-libsolr.
Preparing to unpack .../dse-libsolr_4.8.1-1_all.deb ...
/usr/share/dse/backups exists, indicating a prior standalone installation. Please remove that first
Selecting previously unselected package dse-libsqoop.
Preparing to unpack .../dse-libsqoop_4.8.1-1_all.deb ...
/usr/share/dse/backups exists, indicating a prior standalone installation. Please remove that first
Selecting previously unselected package dse-liblog4j.
Preparing to unpack .../dse-liblog4j_4.8.1-1_all.deb ...
/usr/share/dse/backups exists, indicating a prior standalone installation. Please remove that first
Selecting previously unselected package dse-libmahout.
Preparing to unpack .../dse-libmahout_4.8.1-1_all.deb ...
/usr/share/dse/backups exists, indicating a prior standalone installation. Please remove that first
Selecting previously unselected package dse-libspark.
Preparing to unpack .../dse-libspark_4.8.1-1_all.deb ...
/usr/share/dse/backups exists, indicating a prior standalone installation. Please remove that first
Selecting previously unselected package dse-full.
Preparing to unpack .../dse-full_4.8.1-1_all.deb ...
/usr/share/dse/backups exists, indicating a prior standalone installation. Please remove that first


stderr:
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (Dialog frontend will not work on a dumb terminal, an emacs shell buffer, or without a controlling terminal.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
debconf: (This frontend requires a controlling tty.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin: 
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/dse-libhadoop_4.8.1-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/dse-libhadoop-native_4.8.1-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/dse-libcassandra_4.8.1-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/dse_4.8.1-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/dse-libhive_4.8.1-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/dse-hive_4.8.1-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/dse-demos_4.8.1-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/dse-libpig_4.8.1-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/dse-pig_4.8.1-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/dse-libtomcat_4.8.1-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/dse-libsolr_4.8.1-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/dse-libsqoop_4.8.1-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/dse-liblog4j_4.8.1-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/dse-libmahout_4.8.1-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/dse-libspark_4.8.1-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/dse-full_4.8.1-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/dse-libhadoop_4.8.1-1_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/dse-libhadoop-native_4.8.1-1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/dse-libcassandra_4.8.1-1_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/dse_4.8.1-1_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/dse-libhive_4.8.1-1_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/dse-hive_4.8.1-1_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/dse-demos_4.8.1-1_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/dse-libpig_4.8.1-1_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/dse-pig_4.8.1-1_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/dse-libtomcat_4.8.1-1_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/dse-libsolr_4.8.1-1_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/dse-libsqoop_4.8.1-1_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/dse-liblog4j_4.8.1-1_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/dse-libmahout_4.8.1-1_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/dse-libspark_4.8.1-1_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/dse-full_4.8.1-1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried to uninstall and reinstall Datastax Enterprise multiple times, but I had always the same result.

I've also tried to re-create the VM2 from scratch, hoped that the first VM was completely screwed, but it didn't help.

Any help it's really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like the DSE Standalone Installer was used on the machine prior to trying to provision through OpsCenter, which uses the deb/rpm packages.  I'm basing this off of the following from your apt-get install output: "/usr/share/dse/backups exists, indicating a prior standalone installation. Please remove that first".  You should be able to uninstall this by running /usr/share/dse/uninstall.  You can also try manually removing the /usr/share/dse/backups folder afterward if it sticks around.

Comment: I tried. I've also tried to run apt-get purge "datastax-*" "dse-*", install the same verision of Cassandra on VM2, and then run the add node procedure from OpsCenter....nothing of those worked. I am really out of ideas.

Comment: So the machine with the problem does not have a /usr/share/dse/backup folder? If so we need to get rid of that, as the packages intentionally prevent installation if that's there to avoid conflicts with the standalone installer. If it's not there, then you should not get that error... if you do, let's dig into that some more. On a side note... the package install on that node by itself works fine? The issue only happens once you do the adding of the node via opscenter?

Comment: Did you create a /usr/share/dse/backups folder yourself maybe? If so, please remove it.

Comment: No, there is no such directory. VM2 is basically clean now as I purge every "dse" or "datastax" package with apt-get purge, and run the script for clean the installation I found on Datastax doc. I am definitely doing something wrong due to my lack of experience with Linux, Cassandra and Datastax. Assuming that I have delete everything from VM2 (including Cassandra), what should be the right step by step procedure to follow in order to create and add a second node to my cluster?

Comment: Can you please confirm with an "ls /usr/share/dse" on the machine where you try to install that this directory is really not there (sorry to be persistent). The thing is that that particular directory will survive uninstalls, that's it's purpose (as a permanent way to recover prior configurations for the standalone installer).

Comment: So just to test this... could you run this script on your failing VM? (pardon the formatting, not sure how to do this in comments, the if, echo and fi are all on separate lines):
    `if [ -d /usr/share/dse/backups ]; then
      echo "/usr/share/dse/backups exists, indicating a prior standalone installation. Please remove that first"
      exit 1
    fi`

Comment: The folder wasn't there, but I was eventually able to add the node. What happen is that ops installed a different version of dse (and Cassandra) on VM2. In order to let dse start on VM2, I had to change the cassandra.yaml (remove prop. [optional]). Now opscenter can see both nodes, but still there is a problem: on the dashbord there is a alert which says **"One or more of your nodes are not running the same version of DataStax Enterprise Server. Below is a list of all running versions: VM2 4.8.1 VM1:4.8.5"**.

Comment: I ended up remove (again) everything from VM2, update VM1 using the dse .run file, and install dse with the same .run file on VM2. At that point I had another error when I tried to run nodetool: **"Found multiple DSE core jar files in /usr/share/dse/lib /usr/share/dse/resources/dse/lib /usr/share/dse /usr/share/dse/common**". I just renamed the dse jar files (ver. 4.8.1) present on /usr/share/dse. Then I started the dse service on VM2 and boom! My cluster now has two healty nodes!

Comment: Glad to hear, and sorry for the rough time to get it up and running. This should be much easier, we will look into this some more to understand why this was such a drag. The last issue you ran into seems to indicate to me that somehow there was a mix of installer technologies still going on. A "proper" upgrade should have removed the previous jar. I will follow up internally to try to reproduce this.

Comment: So I think I see where the problem is here. You did use the standalone installer for your initial setup (the *.run application). If you plan to use opscenter for upgrading your cluster, you probably want to start with packages, as that is what opscenter is using. It does get messed up by finding a standalone installer setup on the node, pretty much the way you saw. Although I don't understand why you did not see the backup folder as indicated by the package install... I suspect that may be a transitory issue (it's gone by the time you check).